# Filtering the child nodes of an Elem in scala?

Tags: xml, scala

I'm trying to access the child nodes of some XML that looks a bit like this:

```xml
<msgGrp>
    <msg>a</msg>
    <msg>b</msg>
     <x>c</x>
     <y>d</y>
     <msg>e</msg>
<msgGrp>
```

As you can see, there can be any number of "msg" elements, and exactly one of all of the other kinds of things. I wanted to write a function to grab the msg elements only, and then grab the non-msg elements only. I came up with something like this:

```scala
val messages    = n \ "msg"
val non_mesages = (n \ "_").filter(_.label != "msg")
```

But is there a more concise way of saying "any message where the label isn't 'msg'"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val (messages, non_messages) = (n \ "_").partition(_.label == "msg")
```

Comment: Very elegant! I love it.